# DefaultMessage with singular and plural in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want my default message to change depending on the number in count. This is my current code:

```
<FormattedMessage
  defaultMessage="{count} products will be deleted."
  values={{count: countNumbers.data}}
/>
```

I want a logic like so:

```kotlin
if count == 0
    defaultMessage = "No product will be deleted."
if count == 1
    defaultMessage = "{count} product will be deleted."
if count > 1
    defaultMessage = "{count} products will be deleted."
```

How can I implement it?

Comment: make it using 2 FormattedMessage components. handle it inside the component

Comment: @sojin Could you help me out with how that would look like in code?

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple, try this

```
function App(props) {
  const { count, countNumbers } = props;
  let message = "No product will be deleted.";
  if (count === 1) {
    message = `${count} product will be deleted.`;
  } else if (count > 1) {
    message = `${count} products will be deleted.`;
  }
  return (
    <FormattedMessage
      defaultMessage={message}
      values={{ count: countNumbers.data }}
    />
  );
}
```